# Gremlin query to update the vertex property if exists or create new vertex with property

Tags: gremlin

i am trying to upsert vertex if exists , if does not exists create new vertex and add property.
as ID is immutable, cannot update id? how to drop and add it with same query.
what is wrong with the below code?

```
g.V().hasId(sampleVertex.getId()).fold()
    .coalesce(
      _.unfold()
        .property("name",sampleVertex.getName())
        .property("age",sampleVertex.getAge())
        .property("networth",sampleVertex.getNetworth())
        .property("picURL",sampleVertex.getPicURL())
        .property("description",sampleVertex.getDescription()),
      _.addV(sampleVertex.getLabel())
            .property(T.id,sampleVertex.getId())
            .property("name",sampleVertex.getName())
            .property("age", sampleVertex.getAge())
            .property("networth", sampleVertex.getNetworth())
            .property("picURL", sampleVertex.getPicURL())
            .property("description",sampleVertex.getDescription())
).next();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some extra `.` in the query.  You don't need them in front of the first steps for each of the arguments inside of `coalesce()`.  You could also simplify this query by placing the common `property()` steps after the `coalesce()` as the output of that step would be the existing or newly created vertex.

```
g.V().
  hasId(sampleVertex.getId()).
  fold().
  coalesce(
    unfold(),
    addV(sampleVertex.getLabel()).
        property(T.id, sampleVertex.getId())
    ).
    property("name", sampleVertex.getName()).
    property("age", sampleVertex.getAge()).
    property("networth", sampleVertex.getNetworth()).
    property("picURL", sampleVertex.getPicURL()).
    property("description", sampleVertex.getDescription().
    next()
```

If you wanted to drop the vertex in order to change the ID, then you would need to do something like:

```
g.V().
  hasId(sampleVertex.getId()).
  fold().
  coalesce(
    unfold().sideEffect(drop()).
    addV(sampleVertex.getLabel()).
        property(T.id, sampleVertex.getId()),
    addV(sampleVertex.getLabel()).
        property(T.id, sampleVertex.getId())
    ).
    property("name", sampleVertex.getName()).
    property("age", sampleVertex.getAge()).
    property("networth", sampleVertex.getNetworth()).
    property("picURL", sampleVertex.getPicURL()).
    property("description", sampleVertex.getDescription().
    next()
```

Just realize that dropping a vertex also drops all related edges to that vertex at the same time.  If you want to maintain any existing edges, you'll likely want to fetch those in a separate query before this and then recreate them afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, the above query works fine with little modification. Does gremlin provide any options to load bulk data?

Comment: The closest thing would be the io() step [1]. Just remember, TinkerPop is a reference implementation. So things like bulk loading is up to the provider that has implemented TinkerPop. Databases like Amazon Neptune, JanusGraph, CosmosDB, etc. will have their own bulk load features. [1] https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#io-step